# Find exception number into my arithmetic sequence

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need your help. I'm trying to write a program which allow to find the exception number into an arithmetic sequence.
For example I've an int array with this values :
2, 3, 6, 4, 5
The output must be 6 by the way.
But I'm blocked by that. I don't want to use many conditions etc.

```
    public int FindException(int[] sequence)
    {
        int[] orderSequence = sequence.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
        int oldDifference = 0, sequenceDifference = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < orderSequence.Length; i++)
        {
            sequenceDifference = orderSequence[i + 1] - orderSequence[i];

            if (i == 0)
                oldDifference = sequenceDifference;

            if (sequenceDifference != oldDifference)
                return i > 1 ? orderSequence[i + 1] : orderSequence[i - 1];

            oldDifference = sequenceDifference;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What type of 'arithmetic sequence's are possible. Can your defines rules for that?

Comment: `A|i] - A[i-1]` must be a constant, except for the particular number ...

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that you have a sequence of ordered integers, from lower to higher, and you wanna find the one that breaks it.

For each number 'k' in the sequence, test that

- array[k-1] < array[k]
- array[k] < array[k-1]
  If k is the index of the first or last element, respectively skip to check the previous or the following element.

Instead, if the order was from higher to lower, substitute '<' with '>'.

**Edit**: we need more info to come with a correct solution.
In some cases the solution is ambiguous. For example, given the sequence
[2, 4, 7]
it's impossible to say if the increment must be +2, so [2, 4] would be correct and 7 would be wrong, or the increment must be +3, then 2 would be wrong and [4, 7] would be correct.
How do we know what the correct increment is?

Comment: thanks a lot ! I've edit my post with my code but I think it's not efficient and I don't love it so much.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from degenerate cases. If we have `2` or fewer numbers, we *always* have arithmetic sequence.
If we have `3` or more numbers, let's compute *finite differences*: `a[k + 1] - a[k]`. E.g.

```
  array: 1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 9, 11
  fd:      2, 2, 2,-3, 5, 2

  array: 7, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13
  fd:     -4, 2, 2, 2, 2,  

  array: 1, 3, 5, 7, 11, 20
  fd:      2, 2, 2, 2,  9,
```

Can you see what's going on? All differencies *are equal* with exception of one ore two values.
Now two cases:

- if the *only first* difference is exceptional, then `array[0]` is exceptional
- if the `i`-th difference is exceptional, then `array[i+1]` is exceptional

Comment: thanks a lot ! I've edit my post with my code but I think it's not efficient and I don't love it so much.